# How to change POI icons in Skobbler

Tags: skmaps, scoutstyleeditor

Is it possible to change the map POI icons with a custom image or logo? I tried from StyleEditor, but i could change only the color of the selected POI.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the color and texture of that selected POI category

e.g: in the StyleEditor, select "restaurant” from the map and change its color to red->all restaurant POIs will be red.

Each POI has a unique texture ID associated to it (found in the "TexID" text box)
e.g: out-of-the box the restaurant POI has texture id 1020 associated to it

**Changing the ID to another texture ID**: insert the new ID (see Features window at zoom levels 17-18) in the "TexID" text box (make sure that you choose "All Levels" before making the change so that the texture changes is applied at all zoom levels).

**To add a new a new texture**: first, make sure the image you want to add is in PNG format, colour space RGB, and the image resolution is 512x512 px.

- copy the image in StyleEditor/MapResources/Common folder or in the Style's folder (e.g: StyleEditor/DayStyle folder if you are modifying the Daystyle)
- add the texture in the StyleEditor from the Dialogs menu -> “Add Textures” option
- browse for the desired image, in the "Add Textures" dialog box, by pressing the + button
- give it an ID (make sure its unique) by entering it in the TextureID input box
- click Add & OK buttons to finish adding up the new texture

Make sure to save your style